# How to retrieve secret data from vault API using AppRole?

Tags: rest, hashicorp-vault

My HashiCorp vault instance is runnning properly on CentOS7. I enabled AppRole authentication, created a policy and a role, enabled secret engine and created a secret for a client application.

I can retrieve the secret data using root CLI but I can't figure out how to get secret data from HTTP API with my application role using curl. I tried a few endpoint combinations without success. Retrieving the client token works, but I can't get secret data itself.

I wonder if the API endpoint is correct or if there is another setting in play.

**Authentication method**

```
vault auth enable approle
```

**Policy**

```
# File: my_app /etc/vault/my_app.hcl

path "kv/data/foo/*" {
 capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}

# Command line
vault policy write my_app /etc/vault/my_app.hcl
```

**Role**

```
vault write auth/approle/role/my_app policies="my_app"
```

**Secret creation**

```
vault kv put kv/data/foo/user@domain.tld password=1234
```

**API call token request**

```
curl --request POST --data '{"role_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "secret_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}' http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/approle/login | jq
```

Result: Token is properly retrieved

**API call for secret data request**

```
export VAULT_CLIENT_TOKEN=XXXXXXX
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_CLIENT_TOKEN" --request GET "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv/data/foo/user@domain.tld"
```

Result : No secret data retrieved
Output:

> {"errors":[]}

**CLI call for secret data**

```
vault kv get -field=password kv/data/foo/user@domain.tld
```

Output:

> 1234

**Global settings**

```
vault secrets list

Path          Type         Accessor              Description
----          ----         --------              -----------
cubbyhole/    cubbyhole    cubbyhole_xxxxxxxx    per-token private secret storage
identity/     identity     identity_xxxxxxxx     identity store
kv/           kv           kv_xxxxxxxx           n/a
sys/          system       system_xxxxxxxx       system endpoints used for control, policy and debugging
```